# Excel VBA XML Navigation

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I'm having some issues extracting values from some XML using VBA in Excel 2007. Here is a sample of what the data looks like:

```
<work_order xmlns="http://www.sample.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sample.com" id="">
<link rel="self" type="application/xml" href="http://www.sample.com"/>
<work_order_info>...</work_order_info>
<entry_info>...</entry_info>
<posting_info>...</posting_info>
<instructions>...</instructions>
<address_info>...</address_info>
<crew_time>
    <confirm_date>04 Dec 2013</confirm_date>
    <minutes_required>100</minutes_required>
</crew_time>
<wo_products>
    <wo_product>
        <product_description>pants</product_description>
    </wo_product>
    <wo_product>
        <product_description>shirt</product_description>
    </wo_product>
    <wo_product>
        <product_description>shoes</product_description>
    </wo_product>
    <wo_product>
        <product_description>hat</product_description>
    </wo_product>
    <wo_product>
        <product_description>DPSB1</product_description>
    </wo_product>
</wo_products>
```

What I need to do is loop through each of the wo_product nodes and get the product_description. What I have so far is:

```
Dim nodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim node As IXMLDOMNode
Dim oXMLDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set oXMLDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
oXMLDoc.async = False
oXMLDoc.Load "http://www.sample.com"

Set nodeList = oXMLDoc.SelectNodes("/work_order/wo_products/wo_product")

For Each node In nodeList
    Dim description As String
    description = node.SelectSingleNode("//product_description").Text
    MsgBox (description)
Next node
```

It loops through 5 times, but the message box says "pants" every time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `description = node.SelectSingleNode("product_description").Text`.

Comment: I swear I tried this before to no avail. I thought // told it to continue searching from where you currently are? Similar to ./ in a terminal referencing the directly you're in?

Comment: If you want you can try `description = node.SelectSingleNode("./product_description").Text`. `//` is wrong.